# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError and firePropertyChange

Tags: java, swing

If I run this code I get the AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError and firePropertyChange errors. I am working on a java GUI based game. If a button containing 0 count is clicked, I have to find all adjacent cells containing zero until I find no more adjacent 0 cells. Than I am supposed to reveal the non 0 adjacent cells

```
 public void reveal_zero_cell(int r, int c)
{
    if(myGrid.getCountAtLocation(r, c) != 0)
    {

        board[r][c].setText(Integer.toString(myGrid.getCountAtLocation(r, c)));  //up
        if(board[r][c].isEnabled()) {
        cell_checked++;
        board[r][c].setEnabled(false);

        }

        if( (r>0) && !(myGrid.isBombAtLocation(r-1, c)))
        {

            board[r-1][c].setText(Integer.toString(myGrid.getCountAtLocation(r-1, c)));  //up
            if(board[r-1][c].isEnabled()) {
            cell_checked++;
            board[r-1][c].setEnabled(false);

            }


        }
        if((r+1 < NUM_ROWS) && !(myGrid.isBombAtLocation(r+1, c)))
        {
            board[r+1][c].setText(Integer.toString(myGrid.getCountAtLocation(r+1, c)));   //down
            if(board[r+1][c].isEnabled()) {
            cell_checked++;
            board[r+1][c].setEnabled(false);
            }


        }
        if((c+1 <NUM_COLS) && !(myGrid.isBombAtLocation(r, c+1)))
        {
            board[r][c+1].setText(Integer.toString(myGrid.getCountAtLocation(r, c+1))); //right
            if(board[r][c+1].isEnabled()) {
                cell_checked++;
                board[r][c+1].setEnabled(false);
                }



        }
        if((c >0 ) && !(myGrid.isBombAtLocation(r, c-1)) )
        {
            board[r][c-1].setText(Integer.toString(myGrid.getCountAtLocation(r, c-1))); //left
            if(board[r][c-1].isEnabled()) {
                cell_checked++;
                board[r][c-1].setEnabled(false);
                }



        }
        if((r > 0 &&  c>0)&& !(myGrid.isBombAtLocation(r-1, c-1))) 
        {
            board[r-1][c-1].setText(Integer.toString(myGrid.getCountAtLocation(r-1, c-1))); // main dia left corner
            if(board[r-1][c-1].isEnabled()) {
                cell_checked++;
                board[r-1][c-1].setEnabled(false);
                }




        }
        if((r + 1 < NUM_ROWS) &&(c+1 < NUM_COLS) && !(myGrid.isBombAtLocation(r+1, c+1)))
        {
            board[r+1][c+1].setText(Integer.toString(myGrid.getCountAtLocation(r+1, c+1))); //main dia right corner
            if(board[r+1][c+1].isEnabled()) {
                cell_checked++;
                board[r+1][c+1].setEnabled(false);
                }



        }
        if((r + 1 < NUM_ROWS) &&(c > 0) && !(myGrid.isBombAtLocation(r+1, c-1)))
        {
            board[r+1][c-1].setText(Integer.toString(myGrid.getCountAtLocation(r+1, c-1))); //2nd dia left corner
            if(board[r+1][c-1].isEnabled()) {
                cell_checked++;
                board[r+1][c-1].setEnabled(false);
                }




        }
        if((r > 0 ) &&(c +1 < NUM_COLS) && !(myGrid.isBombAtLocation(r-1, c+1)))
        {
            board[r-1][c+1].setText(Integer.toString(myGrid.getCountAtLocation(r-1, c+1))); //2nd dia right corner
            if(board[r-1][c+1].isEnabled()) {
                cell_checked++;
                board[r-1][c+1].setEnabled(false);
                }

        return;
    }
    }
    else {

        if(myGrid.getCountAtLocation(r, c) == 0)
        {
            board[r][c].setText(Integer.toString(myGrid.getCountAtLocation(r, c)));
            if(board[r][c].isEnabled()) {
                cell_checked++;
                board[r][c].setEnabled(false);
                }
        }

        if( (r>0) && myGrid.getCountAtLocation(r-1, c) == 0)
        {
            board[r-1][c].setText(Integer.toString(myGrid.getCountAtLocation(r-1, c)));  //up

            if(board[r-1][c].isEnabled()) {
                cell_checked++;
                board[r-1][c].setEnabled(false);
                }

             reveal_zero_cell(r-1,c);


        }
        if((r+1 < NUM_ROWS) && myGrid.getCountAtLocation(r+1, c) == 0)
        {
            board[r+1][c].setText(Integer.toString(myGrid.getCountAtLocation(r+1, c)));   //down

            if(board[r+1][c].isEnabled()) {
                cell_checked++;
                board[r+1][c].setEnabled(false);
                }

             reveal_zero_cell(r+1,c);


        }
        if((c+1 <NUM_COLS) && myGrid.getCountAtLocation(r, c+1) == 0)
        {
            board[r][c+1].setText(Integer.toString(myGrid.getCountAtLocation(r, c+1))); //right
            if(board[r][c+1].isEnabled()) {
                cell_checked++;
                board[r][c+1].setEnabled(false);
                }


             reveal_zero_cell(r,c+1);


        }
        if((c >0 ) && myGrid.getCountAtLocation(r, c-1) == 0)
        {
            board[r][c-1].setText(Integer.toString(myGrid.getCountAtLocation(r, c-1))); //left

            if(board[r][c-1].isEnabled()) {
                cell_checked++;
                board[r][c-1].setEnabled(false);
                }


             reveal_zero_cell(r,c-1);

        }
        if((r > 0 &&  c>0) && myGrid.getCountAtLocation(r-1, c-1) == 0) 
        {
            board[r-1][c-1].setText(Integer.toString(myGrid.getCountAtLocation(r-1, c-1))); // main dia left corner

            if(board[r-1][c-1].isEnabled()) {
                cell_checked++;
                board[r-1][c-1].setEnabled(false);
                }



             reveal_zero_cell(r-1,c-1);


        }
        if((r + 1 < NUM_ROWS) && (c +1 < NUM_COLS) && myGrid.getCountAtLocation(r+1, c+1) == 0 )
        {
            board[r+1][c+1].setText(Integer.toString(myGrid.getCountAtLocation(r+1, c+1))); //main dia right corner

            if(board[r+1][c+1].isEnabled()) {
                cell_checked++;
                board[r+1][c+1].setEnabled(false);
                }

             reveal_zero_cell(r+1,c+1);


        }
        if((r + 1 < NUM_ROWS) &&(c > 0) && myGrid.getCountAtLocation(r+1, c-1) == 0)
        {
            board[r+1][c-1].setText(Integer.toString(myGrid.getCountAtLocation(r+1, c-1))); //2nd dia left corner

            if(board[r+1][c-1].isEnabled()) {
                cell_checked++;
                board[r+1][c-1].setEnabled(false);
                }

             reveal_zero_cell(r+1,c-1);
            }


        if((r > 0 ) &&(c +1 < NUM_COLS) && myGrid.getCountAtLocation(r-1, c+1) == 0)
        {
            board[r-1][c+1].setText(Integer.toString(myGrid.getCountAtLocation(r-1, c+1))); //2nd dia right corner

            if(board[r-1][c+1].isEnabled()) {
                cell_checked++;
                board[r-1][c+1].setEnabled(false);
                }

            reveal_zero_cell(r-1,c+1);
            }

        }

}
```

Comment: Non-terminating recursion may result in stack overflow.

Comment: The base case is  myGrid.getCountAtLocation(r, c) != 0